# java: module not found: validatorfx IntellijIDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

it's my First Time working on JavaFX project with IntelliJ IDEA, so I'm facing this problem when Running Project

it Shows Error Message (java: module not found: validatorfx)

Note: My Java Version [java version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRqSV.jpg)

i already searched for Solution and can't Fixed the problem ..

Please note iam just beginner :) !

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the "dependency" tag of validatorfx to your "pom.xml"?

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.synedra</groupId>
 <artifactId>validatorfx</artifactId>
 <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I got the dependency from here: https://github.com/effad/ValidatorFX

After that you have to reload your dependencies with the reload button that appears at the right top corner in your "pom.xml".

Comment: Still same problem

Answer (score 0):

In the file `module-info.java` you can change `requires validatorfx;` on

```
requires net.synedra.validatorfx;
```

It helped me.
It's an answer from Keith Pyle
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4404712032146-Gradle-and-Modules-not-working-